# Phase locked-loop and DSSS

Tags: digital-communications

Suppose we use a DSSS system such that each modulation symbol is spread by a different code. On reception, the signal has a frequency drift and a phase-locked loop (PLL) must be used to correct it. However, this loop is set up during the demodulation step. But when we despread the message received by the different sequences, the estimated modulated message should be completely wrong. Due to frequency drift, a spreading symbol may be despread with the wrong sequence.

As a result, the PLL would become useless normally? So what is its use in a DSSS?